# ASP.NET Core - Hash character (#) sent in a Facebook signon redirection is causing problems

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to sign users on to Facebook from a new ASP.NET Core app.  I am not using an SDK for a number of reasons. Everything's going fine.  I redirect the user to the Facebook sign on page.  The user signs in. Facebook redirects to the following Uri string, which I copied from the browser after the redirection:

```
http://localhost:5000/signonok?#state=testsession&access_token=bbbbtokeneeee&expires_in=510000
```

The signonokController activates but the query collection is empty and the QueryString is "?".  It would appear that the hash character(#) in the string is causing ASP.NET to stop further parsing.  I rummaged around the HttpContext for a few hours and cannot find the state, access_token or expires_in key value pairs.

No errors are being thrown, or issues logged to the logger.

I thought that perhaps I could get to the information, or reformat the Uri, by inserting my own Middleware function into the pipeline.  As suspected I got the same result.

My guess is that it will be easier to work around this issue on my side than it would be to get Facebook to change their response.

Java script is something I would rather avoid in this case, again for a number of reasons not relevant here.

Any thoughts on how to deal with this # character?  I either did something wrong that caused it to be emitted or I have to figure out how to consume the Uri in the pipeline.

Cheers...

Answer (score 1):

> It would appear that the hash character(#) in the string is causing ASP.NET to stop further parsing.

The hash part of the URL is not even *send* to the server; there *is* nothing for your code to parse here.

> My guess is that it will be easier to work around this issue on my side than it would be to get Facebook to change their response.

All you have to do is pass the right value for `response_type` in your login dialog call, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#login:

> **response_type**
>   Determines whether the response data included when the redirect back to the app occurs is in URL parameters or fragments.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured this out last night using Fiddler but was too tired to post.  I changed the response type to "code" and Facebook stopped fragmenting the URL.  It also means that we have make an additional HTTP POST call to convert the "code" to a token.  No big deal but more response time and I suspect a little better security.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the original, unparsed URL using the [RawUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl(v=vs.110).aspx) property.  From there  you can:

1. Remove the # symbol and parse the remaining arguments yourself with a bit of code, or
2. Issue a self-redirect, passing the cleansed URL.  When your server receives the redirect you can then access the querystring parameters using the usual means.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  No joy so far.   There is no RawUrl property in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext . Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.UriHelper.GetEncodedUrl(this.Request); returns:  http://localhost:5000/signonOk?